# Does a PHP array need to be declared before use?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

While writing a recent application I accidentally started filling an array before I had declared it.

```
error_reporting ( E_ALL);  
$array['value'] = 'Test string';
```

I use E_ALL error reporting and an error was not thrown. Is this correct? And if so, are there any issues with declaring array values whilst never declaring the actual array?
Perhaps it just doesn't follow good programming standards.

Comment: When you say "not thrown" do you mean it didn't show on screen or it wasn't logged (if your logging level is set correctly). If it got logged and didn't show check your display_errors setting in your php.ini (Should be set to 1) - This is a good reference: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> While writing a recent application I
>   accidentally started filling an array
>   before I had declared it.

PHP is a weakly typed language. Your statement:

```
$array['value'] = 'Test string';
```

is an implicit declaration (through assignment) of an associative array. So, a notice will not be generated.

However, if you were to write:

```
echo $array['value'];
```

before an assigment, then you'll receive an `Undefined variable` notice.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't have to

And yes, it is a good habit to declare the array to increase code redability

Answer (score 4):

To expand on that, no you do not "have" to, but it can be beneficial to.

Also if you have E_NOTICES turned OFF then you will not see errors from an non uninitialized variable. On production you should turn it off, but on development you should turn it ON. It'll allow you to find problems that you might not see.

Comment: I agree.  It's always good practice to declare an array before use.

Comment: Also, no reason to turn it off on production. I mean, if your code is clean nothing will be reported.

Comment: "On production you should turn it off" Why? Sure "dev testing should resolve errors prior to prod", but what if they do not? However unlikely it may be, if there are issues in Prod you want to see them. If you have error reporting to show these even in Prod, and there are errors, then you catch them, and if there are no errors then there are no logs either. So there are no reasons to turn it off in production.