# Using an array without initialization in PHP

Tags: php

In most languages, I have to initialize an associative array before I can use it:

```
data = {}
data["foo"] = "bar"
```

But in PHP I can just do

```
data["foo"] = "bar"
```

Are there any repercussions to doing this? Is this "the right way" to write PHP?

Comment: there's the danger of it not being an array (or an existing array) if it is used somewhere above. Other than that.. no, not a big deal.  But, it is best practice to declare your vars in general

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should an array be declared before using it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14901793), [Is it necessary to declare PHP array before adding values with \[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8246047), [Does a PHP array need to be declared before use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3704557)

Comment: From the docs: As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with []. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php - but aside that, it's organizational preference. The code will function the same if you choose to specify `$data = array('foo' => 'bar');` versus `$data['foo'] = 'bar';`

Comment: you're right @mario, this is a duplicate. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Is the same, but is not a good idea, the next is a copy-paste from php documentation.

> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array. This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and [] may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to initialize variable by a direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's the same, and no you won't find any problem or repercussion.

But if you like you can do this:

`$a = array();`

You can read more in the [PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)